# Count All Prime Numbers that Can be Formed using Digits of a Given Number

Tags: c#, algorithm, loops, while-loop

I am facing a problem while solving this task.
I should write a program which find the count of prime numbers which can be created using digits of given number, but without repetition unless digit itself repeated in given number.
For example, program should give 5 as output for `number = 123`. Because
`{1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 21, 23, 123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321}`
has 5 prime numbers.
But if given `number = 133` then program should count prime number from this list :
`{1, 3, 13, 31, 33, 133, 313, 331}`

Is there any way to write this program without using array? I have searched every source, but still cannot find a solution. If you have any idea, please help.

I am trying to write something like that. But it is still not working. It is not creating number as I want. One-digit numbers is a little bit closer than 3-digit when I enter `123` . Output is like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q5zA.png)

```
        System.Console.WriteLine("Enter the number: ");
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int enteredNumber = number;
        int length = 0;
        while (number != 0)
        {
            length++;
            number /= 10;
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine($"{length} length");
        number = enteredNumber;
        int nDigit = 1;
        int count = 0;
        int temp = number;

        while (nDigit <= length)
        {
            int n = nDigit;

            while (number != 0)
            {
                int digit = number % 10;

                if (nDigit == 1 && isPrime(digit))
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("1-digit prime number : " + digit);
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    int tempNewNumber = digit * Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10, Convert.ToDouble(nDigit - 1)));
                    int newNumber = tempNewNumber;

                    while (temp != 0)
                    {

                        if (nDigit - 2 >= 0)
                        {
                            newNumber += (temp % 10) * Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10, Convert.ToDouble(nDigit - 2)));
                            nDigit--;
                        }

                        if (nDigit == 1)
                        {
                            System.Console.WriteLine("in while : " + newNumber);
                            if (isPrime(newNumber))
                            {
                                System.Console.WriteLine("prime number : " + newNumber);
                                count++;
                            }
                            newNumber = tempNewNumber;
                            nDigit = n;
                        }
                        temp /= 10;
                    }
                    nDigit = n;
                    temp = enteredNumber;

                }
                number /= 10;
            }
            number = enteredNumber;

            nDigit++;
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine("Count : " + count);


    }


    static bool isPrime(int num)
    {
        if (num <= 1) return false;
        int i = 2;
        while (i <= num / 2)
        {
            if (num % i == 0)
                return false;

            i++;
        }

        return true;
    }`
```

Comment: `One-digit numbers is a little bit closer than 3-digit when I enter 123` can you share example?

Comment: I might suggest you separate your code into more discrete methods, like one method that gets and returns and `int` from the user, and one that takes in an `int` and returns a `List<int>` of all permutations of the digits of the input, just like you did with the method that determines if an `int` is a prime number.

Comment: With all due respect this seems overly complex, why not treat the number as a string of characters and filter based on contains?

Comment: @b166er because converting to string or using array not allowed in the task. :'(

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want without arrays: Identify a number by the product of the nth prime number for each digit n.

- If two numbers have the same id, they are digit-wise permutations of each other.
- If the id of one number p is evenly divisibly by the id of another number q, then q has fewer digits than p, but all digits of q can also found in p.

You can now test all numbers in the possible range, for example all numbers with 3 or fewer digits, whether they can be made from the given digit. This is probably not very efficient, especially for large numbers, but hey! – no arrays. (And permutations of large sets have their own performance issues.)

The example code below finds the 16 permutations of 123, but it doesn't check whether the numbers are primes.

```
public class Permutor
{
    static uint[] prime = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29};
 
    static uint code(uint n)
    {
        uint res = 1;
 
        while (n > 0) {
            res *= prime[n % 10];
            n /= 10;
        }
 
        return res;
    }
 
    static uint ceiling(uint n)
    {
        uint c = 1;
 
        while (n > 0) {
            c *= 10;
            n /= 10;
        }
 
        return c;
    }
 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        uint num = 123;
        uint id = code(num);
        uint max = ceiling(num);
 
        for (uint i = 1; i < max; i++) {
            if (id % code(i) == 0) {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There's room for improvement. For example, the actual ceiling for 123 is, of course, 321, so you could try to find that from the code instead of overestimating the ciling to 1000.

When you look for primes, you don't need to visit every number. Except 2 and 3, all prime numbers are either `2*k - 1` or `2*k + 1`.